# What's the benefit of giving through the Combined Federal Campaign?

Tags: united-states, charity

The [Combined Federal Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Federal_Campaign), from what I understand, solicits donations from federal employees and distributes them to charities. That's great if they can encourage more giving from their audience (federal workers).

But I'm trying to figure out why I would give through them rather than continue to give directly to individual charities? Their [FAQ](https://www.opm.gov/combined-federal-campaign/donating-through-cfc/#url=FAQs) says nothing about matching funds, and explicitly says donations aren't pre-tax.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this just a way to centralize previously scattered campaigns to solicit giving in the workplace?

Comment: It's almost certainly a convenience factor.: money taken directly out of the paycheck is "unseen"; if you "see" it in your bank account, then -- so the thinking goes -- you're more likely to "spend it on stuff" than giving it to charity, adding to an IRA, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I presume this is, like most such employer-offered campaigns, run by United Way or structured similarly.

Its main advantage to the employer is that it lets them brag about how socially responsible they and their employees are, and perhaps encourage charitable giving from those who otherwise wouldn't consider it. And while matching on these campaigns is uncommon, the employer may toss in a large donation of their own, and pay for the overhead of running the campaign so all of your money goes to the charities.

The main advantage to the employee is that, since it's taken as a payroll deduction, there's nothing for you to remember or handle; that's convenient, and for some payroll deduction is a useful budgeting tool to make sure they don't change their mind later in the year.

The secondary advantage for the employeee is essentially diversification. United Way and the like will get funds to organizations you might not even be aware existed, helping people with problems you may never have considered. If you want to do something for society without doing all the research to decide what your issues are and who you trust to address them, this again can be convenient. On the other hand, the campaign is often focused on a specific subset of the charitable universe; my employer's drive focused on "health and human services" charities, for example, where the choice of which are and aren't eligible depends on which tax-deductable category they're operating in. (I believe our local SPCA is actually incorporated as a human services organization, defensible because having pets has been demonstrated to improve mental health.)

Note that some (not all) such programs offer a "Donor Choice" option where you can direct some or all of the money to specific charities rather than the general pool. There is usually a maximum number of slots which can be used that way; my employer let us pick eight and set the percentage of our deduction to go to each.

My approach was generally to put all my large recurring yearly donations into this campaign, just for convenience. Also, my employer let me set the total deduction to a percentage of my salary, so if I got a raise I automatically donated more to these favorite organizations.

It's a tool. You aren't obligated to use it.

Admittedly, management can sometimes get a bit obnoxious about "Return the form even if you're saying no", both so they can track whether announcements about the campaign are reaching everyone and as a bit of peer pressure to encourage participation. But "no, I'll deal with it myself" *IS* a perfectly reasonable answer, and don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

(Yes, I've served as a canvasser at my employer, back when this was being processed via paper forms in envelopes rather than on line, so I've heard most of the questions before.)